# Declaring a vector with Car() objects prints unrelated error

Tags: c++

I tried to compile the following code and I get this error undefined reference to 'vtable for Car'

 *And marks the Car ctor line as false*

I include "Car.h" and "Road.h" in main() (Road.h already includes Car.h, But Car.h doesn't)

```
class Car
{

protected:
        std::string name;
public:
        Car(std::string name="Ship")
        {
          std::ostringstream tmp;
          std::string temp;
          tmp << name << ++id;
          name = tmp.str();
        }
        static int id = 0;
        virtual void func(); //redefined in the subclasses Turbo and Tank
        virtual void mov(); //redefined in the subclasses Turbo and Tank
};
```

Vector Declaration in main()

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include "Car.h"
#include "Road.h"
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::vector;
int main()
{
     vector<Car> 
     Shipyard( 10, Car() );

}
```

Comment: It is certainly relevant. If you want help with your code you need to post the whole thing.

Comment: @Curufindul It is certainly **not** irrelevant. If you want help you need to show all of it. Are we mind readers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error **undefined reference to 'vtable for "insert ClassName here" '** its actually a linker not a compile error

Do you have any virtual functions that you are not showing us?

If the answer is yes, please comment them, recompile and comment if the error persists.

If not then its not related to this vector declaration

Comment: ok, found it, it was the virtual functions that were in Car.h